# XML array object empty element deserialized - Need to get the attribute values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

I have xml as follows

```
<FbiXml>
  <Ticket>
    <UserID>1</UserID>
    <Key>lEPLCl+NUOv6eOrETE8Row==</Key>
  </Ticket>
  <FbiMsgsRs statusCode="1000">
    <SaveSORs statusCode="2100" statusMessage="Was not able to find the product MGAS003-KT."/>
  </FbiMsgsRs>
</FbiXml>
```

I have relevant serializable class

```
public partial class FbiMsgsRq
{    
    private object[] itemsField;

    [XmlElementAttribute("SOSaveRs", typeof(SaveSORsType),IsNullable = true)]
    [XmlElementAttribute("SaveDiscountRs", typeof(SaveDiscountRsType),IsNullable = true)]
    [XmlElementAttribute("SaveShipmentRs", typeof(SaveShipmentRsType),IsNullable = true)]
    public object[] Items 
    {
         get 
         {
             return this.itemsField;
         }
         set 
         {
             this.itemsField = value;
         }
    }

    ......    
}
```

Problem: **when above xml is deserialized Items property returns me null** , but I have an element inside  this is an empty element. But I have marked Items property in class IsNullable = true make this serialized.

But I am still getting the empty **items** element, I need to get the attributes values of that property. How can this be achieved?